# nosql manager for cassandra how to search date value when the data type is text

Tags: function, date, cassandra

i am using NoSQL Manager for Cassandra tool, i have a table and a column

The column having date value but the column is text. how can i find data between two date range using that text column. does cassandra have todate function like oracle

Answer (score 0):

> does cassandra have todate function like oracle

No

> how can i find data between two date range using that text column

*If* your text column is a clustering key, and *if* it is stored in a format that is appropriately sorted in text ordering (ie ISO 8601) you can simply do a > < where clause. Otherwise it cannot.

If you want to query your data in a way it was not stored, you want to use spark or something to make reading the entire data set more efficient.